# Mapping two table ,React or Sql?and how?

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs, database

Hi there I do have one table called user with the following :

cust_num|trans_num|date_of_transaction|price_of_product|id_of_product

and another table called customer with the following:

cont_id|transaction_id|transaction_date|prod_price_net|prod_id

basically I want to map trough it, in the end I would like to have another table with the mapped values,so joind...
and having this :

- Sum of distinct  “cust_num”
- Sum of distinct “trans_num”
- Average basket of transactions “avg_transactions”

in another table or as query so that I can ask the database that sum and average @.@
Thanks for the help guys much appreciated.

following the suggestion to give example here we go :
user tb

```
cust_num|trans_num|date_of_transaction|price_of_product|id_of_product
100504335|100503936|10/11/2019|67023|100059589
100406909|100402572|3/30/2017|1101|101101914
100006079|100007232|5/21/2013|8530|100055307
```

customer tb

```
cont_id|transaction_id|transaction_date|prod_price_net|prod_id                      
100504335|100503936|10/11/2019|67023|100059589                      
100406909|100402572|3/30/2017|1101|101101914                        
100006079|100007232|5/21/2013|8530|100055307                        
100202212|100202600|4/28/2018|470|101101914                     
100003470|100019059|3/19/2019|20844|790199694                       
100003470|100003687|9/8/2010|20000|790005573                        0
```

mapped tb

```
c_id|      t_id|     t_d|     p_pe_n|  p_id                     
100504335|100503936|10/11/2019|67023|100059589                      
100406909|100402572|3/30/2017|1101|101101914                        
100006079|100007232|5/21/2013|8530|100055307                        
100202212|100202600|4/28/2018|470|101101914                     
100003470|100019059|3/19/2019|20844|790199694                       
100003470|100003687|9/8/2010|20000|790005573
```

result

```
sum_price_cust| sum_of_t| avg_t                     
67023|1|1                       
1101|1| 1               
8530|1| 1                   
470|1|  1               
20844+20000|2|  2
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I edited the post , thanks Gordon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(m.price_of_product) as sum_price_cust,
  COUNT(m.cust_num) as sum_of_t,
  SUM(m.price_of_product) / COUNT(m.cust_num) as avg_t
FROM (SELECT u.cust_num, u.trans_num, u.date_of_transaction, u.price_of_product, u.id_of_product
  FROM user u
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.*
  FROM customer c
) m
GROUP BY m.cust_num
```

Not quite sure if average number is what you want though.